# Why is に used in the sentence 大ピンチに勝機が見えた?

Tags: particle-に

Why is there a に particle here? I dont see it fitting any of the roles I know for it (indirect object, indicating a source or agent, frequency, a specific point in time, purpose, direction of action, location of existence..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible interpretations. 
One is a specific point in time, that is, "in (the moment of) the crisis".

The other is a marker to indicate the background for the object in your view. e.g. (1) 壁**に**模様が見える: a pattern is seen <s>against</s> **on** the wall. (2) 夕日**に**映える雲: clouds that manifest **against** the sunset.

Answer (score -3):

> に： the roles I know for it (indirect object, indicating a source or agent, frequency, a specific point in time, purpose, direction of action, location of existence..)

Oh, so many and complicated...

大ピンチに in a great pinch (maybe "source" or "indirect or third or fourth object"? My 2 cents is に is just a に or 助詞, suck it up)

勝機が見えた saw a chance of victory (direct object)